# Java documentations in a separate file on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

I've been using Eclipse in my internship, and in the last test I had they gave me a sample of a real project to fix, and the whole code was a freaky mess. Though I've been warned that a complete documentation of a code is not affordable in a day-to-day work, I wanna struggle to try to do it anyway in any code I write from now on.

Just to be clear, the "documentation" I talk about is that piece of comment before any method (JavaDoc), that explains what that method does. It can be viewed when I hover upon it, just like when I do with a String statement.

I know that these comments are inside a class within the Java source code.

[image: JavaDoc example]

But I think leaving that Javadoc inside the file ruins the legibility of my code, so the question is: is there a way to keep these Javadoc documentations in a separate file, delete them in my code, but still be visible when I hover in my methods?

I already tried to "Generate Javadoc", but since I deleted it in my code, the hover thing didn't work anymore.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by code "*legibility*"  that Javadoc ruins?  Have you looked at the source code of Java classes?

Comment: If you have properly made javadoc in the code, then you can generate javadoc in html format via IDE, is this, what are you asking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaDocs must be in-line. It makes sense when you think about it. If you were to change a method's signature or behaviour and the documentation for that method was off in some other file, you'd very quickly end up with documentation that is inaccurate and therefore useless. People would forget to update it, or they would deliberately avoid doing so because of the hassle.

If the length of the comments annoys you, IDEs like IntelliJ will allow you to collapse JavaDocs (and any other blocks) to hide them:

[image: Before]  [image: After]

It's been a while since I used Eclipse but I suspect it's the same.

"Generate JavaDoc" is a way of parsing your JavaDoc comments and generating HTML which can browsed separately or hosted on a web page, [just like the classes from the JDK have](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

---

Good on you for aspiring to write good-quality documentation, by the way. The world needs more devs like that.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible to put Javadoc elsewhere. The whole idea behind Javadoc is "let's put the documentation directly into source code".

The reason behind it is that for most developers, this is just as far from the actual code as they are willing to look for documentation, and as far away as they can be bothered to go to write some.